# Disable or change TTL of already indexed documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently using Elasticsearch 2.3.2 and would like to increase the TTL of old documents or, disable it in case it cannot be increased.

Is there any way to change this meta field? I tried using the python API and I wasn't able to do so.

Comment: Note that the `_ttl` field [has been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html) in 2.0 and should not be used anymore as it will be removed in future versions.

Comment: Well, that leads me to my other option. What to do with the elements that already have a TTL?

Comment: You can still use the `_ttl` field, however, you're encouraged to use a custom field of your own and manage it by yourself. Maybe you should explain your exact use case a little bit more, so we can figure out the best solution that fits your case.

Comment: I'm storing millions of documents and would like to store them for 2 or 3 years. But, if _ttl is been deprecated I would make my own script in order to delete old documents. But, for deleting the _ttl field (or disable _ttl) I just find the solution of "re-index" all documents without that field.

Comment: Another much simpler solution is to use yearly (or monthly) indices and then delete a whole index when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: That's exactly what my script will do :) I have monthly indices. But need to disable _ttl either way I guess.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!